# Trouble adding a printer with lpadmin

Tags: terminal, printing

I'm trying to add a printer through the Terminal using lpadmin, and it absolutely refuses to work. The printer adds just fine, everything looks perfect from what I can see, but any attempt to print results in a "Printer did not respond" error.

Here's the line I'm using to add the printer:

```
lpadmin -p _1BIT_16x09 -D 1BIT_16x09 -L "Export" -o printer-is-shared=false -E -v lpd://10.96.99.60/1BIT_16X09 -P ~/PPDs/_1BIT_16x09.ppd
```

The reason the -p name has a _ in front of it is because if I add it normally, it adds this, I'm assuming because the name starts with a number. I have crafted it to create the printer to appear exactly the same way within the cups web interface and the `/etc/cups/printers.conf` file.

If I add the printer using the above command (which doesn't work), this is what I get in `printers.conf`:

```
<Printer _1BIT_16x09>
UUID urn:uuid:13a13ddb-3110-37b0-7aab-96bae9e30955
Info 1BIT_16x09
Location Export
MakeModel Agfa ApogeeX
DeviceURI lpd://10.96.99.60/1BIT_16X09
State Stopped
StateMessage The printer did not respond.
StateTime 1464903468
ConfigTime 1464903399
Reason paused
Type 8450124
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

If I add it normally through the GUI (which does work), this is what I get:

```
<Printer _1BIT_16x09>
UUID urn:uuid:c5565ce1-256d-3d66-4fb8-74fde3242cc5
Info 1BIT_16x09
Location Export
MakeModel Agfa ApogeeX
DeviceURI lpd://10.96.99.60/1BIT_16X09
State Idle
StateTime 1464904755
ConfigTime 1464904755
Type 8450124
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

As far as I can tell, aside from the UUID they are identical, but one works and the other doesn't. It's driving me bonkers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, embarrassingly enough, turned out to be an uppercase letter in the lpadmin command I was using.

Comment: And that uppercase letter in the  command would be......

Comment: It was in the queue name. Apparently when I was looking at the printers.conf file it hadn't updated, so I couldn't see the change between upper and lowercase in the 16X09 vs 16x09.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect a permissions issue. I would disable and enable the printer with `cuspdisable` and `cupsenable` to see what it returns and what happens then.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. I opened a bug report with Apple and they've asked for additional information. Hopefully they'll patch it in an upcoming update.